# Get char at index location in char array Assembly X86 embedded

Tags: arrays, x86, inline-assembly

I am having a lot of trouble accessing a value in an array of chars at a specific location. I am using inline-assembly in C++ and using visual studio (if that is of any help). Here is my code:

```
char* addTwoStringNumbers(char *num1)
{
    // here is what I have tried so far:
    movzx eax, num1[3];
    mov al, [eax]
}
```

When I debug, I can see that num1[3] is the value I want but I can't seem to make either `al` or `eax` equal that value, it seems to always be some pointer reference. I have also played around with Byte PTR with no luck.

Comment: You should post *real* code.  That fragment is not valid, you have to at least tell the C++ compiler that the code body is assembler else it will attempt to parse it as C++ code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f7adz6y%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not good neither at inline assembly, neither at MASM syntax, but here are some hints:

1) Try this:

```
mov   eax, num1 ;// eax points to the beggining of the string
movsx eax, [eax + some_index] ;// movsx puts the char num1[some_index] in eax with sign extend.
```

(movzx is for unsigned char, so we used movsx)

2) You need to pass the value from `eax` to C. The simpliest way is to declare a variable and to put results there: `int rez; __asm { mov rez, eax; };`

3) If you want to write the whole function in assembly, you should consider using the `naked` keyword (and read about calling conventions). If not, make sure you preserve registers and don't damage the stack.

Comment: works perfectly! Thank you so much for the help. I will look into the naked keyword

Comment: @Quentin Also try NASM without any VS around. It will help better to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone's doing their ICS 51 homework! Follow ruslik's advice and you'll be done in no time.